# Create nested json blobs in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I'm trying to create a nested json from a table like this:

```
+----------+---------+------------------------------+
| unixtime | assetid |             data             |
+----------+---------+------------------------------+
|       10 |      80 | {"inflow": 10, "outflow": 2} |
|       20 |      90 | {"inflow": 10, "outflow": 2} |
|       10 |      80 | {"inflow": 10, "outflow": 2} |
|       20 |      90 | {"inflow": 10, "outflow": 2} |
+----------+---------+------------------------------+
```

and get something like this:

```
{
    "10": {
        "80": {"inflow": 10, "outflow": 2},
        "90": {"inflow": 10, "outflow": 2}
    },
    "20": {
        "80": {"inflow": 10, "outflow": 2},
        "90": {"inflow": 10, "outflow": 2}
    }
}
```

I've tried recursively converting the json data to text, array_agg then convert the result to json blob using json_object, but that eventually screwed up the json structure with escape slashes ( \ ).

Any help would be appreciated

Here's the link to the data:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=26734e87d4b9aea4ceded4e414acec4c

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `json_object_agg()` function:

```
....
, m as (
select
    unixdatetime,
    assetid,
    json_object(array_agg(description), array_agg(value::text))
    as value
from input_data
group by unixdatetime, assetid
), j as
(
select json_object_agg("assetid","value") as js,m."unixdatetime"
  from m
 group by "unixdatetime" 
)
select json_object_agg("unixdatetime",js)
  from j
```

Comment: thanks! Can't believe I spent 2 hours on this. This looks like a cleaner and faster way than json_object and array agg isn't it?